# How can we add authorization for graphql api in Django graphene?

Tags: security, graphql, authorization, graphene-django, django-graphql-jwt

I am using React Native as client and Django Graphene at Backend.Also i am using django-graphql-auth for login. I am getting token and refresh token from tokenAuth mutation. But currently if anyone knows my mutation or query along with graphql end url, he can access the data from backend. How can i use token or refresh token to authorise access only to authenticated users?